# How can I write a function in Racket that pads numbers without conditionals?

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I need to write a function that consumes a Nat and returns a Str, padded to three digits.

Example:

```
(pad3 7) => "007"
(pad3 42) => "042"
(pad3 245) => "245"
(pad3 3141592) => "314"
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

In Racket, you can use [`~r`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=~r#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7er%29%29) to convert a number to a string while controlling padding, min-width etc. as follows:

```
(~r 7 #:min-width 3 #:pad-string "0")
=> "007"
```

But, since you also want to set a max-width that cuts off any digits after the third position from the left, you can apply [`substring`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._substring%29%29) on the newly converted string as follows:

```
(substring (~r 3141592 #:min-width 3 #:pad-string "0") 0 3)
=> "314"
```

Here is a sample `pad3` implementation:

```
(define (pad3 num)
  (substring (~r num #:min-width 3 #:pad-string "0") 0 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Three Most Significant Digits**

1. Convert the number to a string

   - Use `number->string`
2. Find the length of the string

   - Use `string-length`
3. Find the number of zeros to prepend

   - Use `(max 0 (min 3 (- 3 n)))` where `n` is the length of the string
4. Use `make-string` to produce a string with zeros
5. Prepend the zero-string with `string-append`
6. Use `substring` to pick out the first 3 characters.

**Three Least Significant Digits**

1. Get the three least significant digits

   - Use `(remainder _ 1000)`
2. Add 1000 the number

   - you now have 1xxx where xxx is the output you want
3. Use `integer->string` to get a string.
4. Use `substring` to remove the prefixed 1.